# iScroll and Fixed Document Problem

Tags: position, fixed, iscroll4

I am using iScroll and it's working perfect. When it comes to form elements like input and select, it works though when one taps these elements the iphone keypad comes up and the element has to be focused which makes sense. But this also moves the document scroller to top hiding the header which I don't want.

Would you help me write a function which will sense if there are elements focused and then preventDefault it but scrollTo the iScroll instead of window.iScroll.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Hey Umair, were you able to fix this issue?  I'm running into something that sounds nearly identical.  I have a banner div above an iscroll div with text fields in the iscroll div.  When I select a field the field is moved into focus correctly when the keyboard comes up.  However, when I use the next/previous buttons to navigate the fields it's possible to get into a state where the focused text elms are under the banner.  When I close the keyboard the vertical scroll gets stuck with a negative vertical position under the banner...  Any ideas?